# Issue setting up GIT with SSH on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, git

I´m following the steps outlined in Tim Davis´ blog for setting up GIT with copSSH on Windows (http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/) but I´m having problems. I´ve gotten up to step 15 under the Installing Putty instructions but rather than getting a "Enter Login" message, I´m getting a "Network Error: Unable to connect to server" error. 
I know that it could potentially be a myriad of things but I was wondering if by some miracle, someone could give me some ideas of what else I should check?
 
I´ve doublechecked the following:

- IP address is correct
- User has been added to copSSH
- Key is stored in the specified user folder
- Rule has been added to Firewall
  (NOTE: We´re using a server on 1and1.com and the firewall rules allow us to specify a local port and a remote port. Have configured to local port 4837 and remote port to Any).
  I tried to doublecheck if the SSH service is running but I don´t know what it´s called. I noted down the username and password from the copSSH setup but I haven´t seen anything remotely similar to SSH in the list of services.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! I´ve never had to do something like this before so I´m a little lost.
Regards,
Kat

Answer (score 1):

### Troubleshooting

Are you specifying port 4837 in the Putty window?

I personally suggest using OpenSSH or [SmartGit](http://www.shareit.com/affiliate.html?affiliateid=200142144&publisherid=200020344&target=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.syntevo.com%2Fsmartgit%2Findex.html), not Putty... I've seen too many issues with it.

Also, I suspect your firewall configuration needs to be local port=Any and remote port=4837.

### The 5 minute shortcut

[This installer sets up a windows git *server* using CopSSH](http://windowsgit.com). It configures the firewall, the user accounts, and gives you a GUI for all the SSH and keys stuff. It costs $9, but it saves hours of configuration (it's a 5 minute, 3-step install). It has a self-contained Git install, so no conflicts should happen.

**NOTE**: I'm the webmaster of [windowsgit.com](http://windowsgit.com). I got the project started after taking a good look at [Davis' tutorial](http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/) and thinking.... oh, ----! The CopSSH author and I collaborated to make the automate the process and reduce the number of frustration-related keyboard deaths :)